# converting Decimal to HexaDeceimal

Tags: c#, algorithm

```
int DecimalNum=45,temp=0,i=0;
char[] hexcode = new char[10];
while(DecimalNum != 0)
{
    temp = DecimalNum%16;
    if(temp <10)
    {
        hexcode[i]=Convert.ToChar(temp+48);
        i++;
    }
    else if(temp >=10)
    {
        hexcode[i]=Convert.ToChar(temp+55);
        i++;
    }
    DecimalNum=DecimalNum/16;

}
```

O/P: 2D

Can someone please explain me why we are adding 48 and 55 before converting to Char?

Comment: It's probably something to do with the unicode values of the hex characters(look into Convert.ToChar). There are easier ways to convert between hex and decimal, such as `Convert.ToInt32(number, 16);` and `int.Parse(number, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)`

Comment: @jreese Those are definitely preferable. The only reason to write one's own hex-dec converter is for the learning experience. Which I assume is the OP's motivation.

Comment: replace those pieces of code with `temp + '0'` and `temp - 10 + 'a'` and it becomes more legible and maintainable. For instance, switch from `a` to `A` without knowing any ASCII codes. C# will do `char + int`.

Comment: @S.L.Barth He did not write this, you can tell because he doesn't know how it works.

Answer (score 2):

The representation of 0 in the ASCII table is 48.
The representation of A in the ASCII table is 65, and the value A in hexa is 10 (65-10 = 55)

Answer (score 1):

Those are the ASCII codes for the characters `0` and `A`.

If you didn't  do this, `ToChar` would convert the values to the ASCII symbols stsarting at index 0 and index 10, respectively.

I find it a pretty crude way to do this, to be fair. I'd prefer to have a string `"01234567890ABCDEF"`, and use indices in this string. Then you are not bound to the underlying character representations of the system.